# Issues with function

Tags: javascript

I am newbie. I am doing exercise calculate triangle area but I have trouble. While I run program to calculate, error display. The solution always display 0. This is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Square Triangle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="solution"></p>
    <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" placeholder="Enter first value" />
    <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" placeholder="Enter second value" />
    <input type="text" name="number3" id="number3" placeholder="Enter third value" />
    <input type="button" value="Click to calc" onclick="calculateTriangleSquare()"/>
    <script>
            const a = document.getElementById("number1").value;
            const b = document.getElementById("number2").value;
            const c = document.getElementById("number3").value;
        function calculateTriangleSquare() {
            let p = (a + b + c) / 2;
            let S = Math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
            document.getElementById("solution").innerHTML = S;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix it. Please help me. Thank you every much.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: try outputting the values as you make calculations , you can also use console.log to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes,

1. You are not grabbing the input values when the function is called. You do not want to access the values outside of the function.
2. You are not parsing the values as integers. They are being concatenated and then divided by 2, so `p` would equal `'000' / 2 = 0`.

```js
function calculateTriangleSquare() {
  const a = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value, 10);
  const b = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value, 10);
  const c = parseInt(document.getElementById("number3").value, 10);

  let p = (a + b + c) / 2;
  let S = Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
  document.getElementById("solution").innerHTML = S;
}
```

```html
<p id="solution"></p>
<input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" placeholder="Enter first value" />
<input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" placeholder="Enter second value" />
<input type="text" name="number3" id="number3" placeholder="Enter third value" />
<input type="button" value="Click to calc" onclick="calculateTriangleSquare()" />
```

If your values represent a vector, you can just pass them as an array of form values.

```js
const solution = document.querySelector('#solution');

const calculateTriangleSquare = button => {
  const argv = button.closest('form')['argv[]'],
    [ a, b, c ] = [ ...argv ].map(input => parseInt(input.value, 10)),
    p = (a + b + c) / 2;
  solution.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
}
```

```css
.info label { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<h1>Calcuate Square Triangle</h1>
<form name="calulate-triangle-square" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="number" name="argv[]" value="3">
  <input type="number" name="argv[]" value="4">
  <input type="number" name="argv[]" value="5">
  <button onclick="calculateTriangleSquare(this)">Calculate</button>
</form>
<br>
<div class="info">
  <label>Solution:</label>
  <span id="solution"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank for supporting me to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you get the values from your inputs when the page finishes loading. After you enter a value in any of them, the values for a, b and c are not updated. You should get the values from the inputs in your calculateTriangleSquare function and parse them to numbers:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Square Triangle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="solution"></p>
    <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" placeholder="Enter first value" />
    <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" placeholder="Enter second value" />
    <input type="text" name="number3" id="number3" placeholder="Enter third value" />
    <input type="button" value="Click to calc" onclick="calculateTriangleSquare()" />
    <script>
      const aInput = document.getElementById('number1');
      const bInput = document.getElementById('number2');
      const cInput = document.getElementById('number3');
      function calculateTriangleSquare() {
        const [a, b, c] = [aInput, bInput, cInput].map((el) => +el.value);
        const p = (a + b + c) / 2;
        const S = Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
        document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML = S;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. I have understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There a few minor issues with your code, but i will explain it to you,

1. Your a,b,c cant be something else than 0, because they are first constants and secondly you dont change the value of a,b,c once the function is called, but only before you call it. You need to refresh the values when you call the function.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Square Triangle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="solution"></p>
    <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" placeholder="Enter first value" />
    <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" placeholder="Enter second value" />
    <input type="text" name="number3" id="number3" placeholder="Enter third value" />
    <input type="button" value="Click to calc" onclick="calculateTriangleSquare()"/>
    <script>
            
        function calculateTriangleSquare() {
            let a = document.getElementById("number1").value;
            let b = document.getElementById("number2").value;
            let c = document.getElementById("number3").value;
            let p = (a + b + c) / 2;
            let S = Math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
            document.getElementById("solution").innerHTML = S;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers